# Plotly in R not recognizing/plotting data retrieved from readxl package

Tags: r, plotly, shiny, readxl

A few months ago, I built a shiny app, with a plotly graph as my main output. My data is from an excel sheet, and I have used the `readxl` package to pull the data into R. 
I recently updated the excel data, and now plotly will no longer graph the data.
From the shinyapp:

```
ratings <- read_excel("data/excel.xlsx", sheet = "Ratings")
p <- plot_ly(ratings, x = ratings[,1], 
             y = ratings[,input$select[1]],
             name = input$select[1])
```

is the beginning building block for the output. When I launch the app, I see an error message

> Error: Unsupported index type: NULL

where the plot used to be.
I have tried to build the plot step-by-step in RStudio, but my output is a blank x,y graph without any data points. If I manually build vectors:

```
xVector <- c(1:5)
yVector <- c(1:5)
plot_ly(x = xVector, y = yVector)
```

I get a fully-functioning `plotly` graph.

Answer (score 2):

After researching all day, I discovered that `readxl` has changed since I originally built the app, such that data is stored as a tibble instead of a data frame, and plotly doesn't recognize tibbles. Using `as.data.frame()` resolved the issue.

Comment: glad that worked. `tibble` inherits `data.frame` so the step should not be necessary.  Might get fixed in the pending plotly release.  Using this, I do not have to explicitly convert with `as.data.frame()`.